# pointing to a parent pom allready installed in the local cache for jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, parent-pom

We have different environments building the same snapshot version of different projects at the same time. We can separate the maven caches, so those snapshots get installed at different places and don't affect each other.

For some reason though I get the following error message when building a child module:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.sample:parent-pom:pom:4.0-SNAPSHOT in http://localhost/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10
```

I can't install the snapshot in nexus, and I can't point to the parent pom in the file system.

The snapshot is already in the cache, so I just maven to continue using it instead of failing. Ideas?

**Update:**

This looks like a jenkins maven problem, if I start the mvn locally at the jenkins machine, same configuration and workspace, it works. I have no idea though how to check what is jenkins actually doing.

Comment: In my company, we have some Maven jobs which use a local cache (in the job's workspace).
These jobs are configured to clean the workspace for every builds (in the SCM properties).
Maybe you can try to configure like that and check if it solves your issue.

Comment: @BrunoLavit thanks for the idea, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. Jenkins runs in a local service account and does not put them in the user directory. Change the `settings.xml` in `maven-home-dir/conf`. I have this in mine.

Put this under settings:

```
<localRepository>C:/maven_repository</localRepository>
```